# Count occurrences after a string match with bash text utilities

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I'm trying to reorganise my desktop with some cool conky config. Since I'm a very big fan of org-mode in Emacs, I'd like to pipe out the tasks from org file where I keep my daily tasks and display it in conky. Say I have a file like this:

```
* first item
** subitem
** subitem
** subitem
* second item
** subitem
** subitem
* third item
** subitem
** subitem
** subitem
** subitem
```

I'd like to create a summary of my tasks that will check all tasks beginning with `*` and count `**` items before it. Then I'd like to present that in a suitable maner:

```
* first item [3]
* second item [2]
* third item [4]
```

While I can find occurrences of strings beginning with only one `*` with `grep`:

```
grep "^\\* " foo.org
```

and I can count occurrences of `**` with:

```
grep -c "^\\*\{2\}" foo.org
```

How can I achieve the desired result? Of course, one can use Python, or Ruby, but I'd like to stick with bash utilities only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the sample file you gave:

```
awk '!/^*/{next}$1=="*"{sub("\\*+ ","");p=$0}$1="**"{c[p]+=1}END{for(i in c) printf "* %s [%s]\n", i ,c[i]-1}'
```

That returns the desired output.

```
* second item [2]
* first item [3]
* third item [4]
```

If you need it sorted, pipe the result in `sort`

```
awk command | sort -k2,2
```

Comment: Neat. But if I have a line that doesn't start with `*`, it's still "counting" it.

Comment: Using grep piped into awk is redundant. I changed the awk filter accordingly.

Comment: You should've removed my "tweak". Neat one! Thanx!

Comment: But I've noticed a strange behaviour: why is `awk` sorting lines on his own?! I can use ` | sort`... nevermind! =)

Comment: @ripat, I like the associative array, but I'm sure you can do this with awk in a way that preserves input ordering :)

Comment: The way awk scan an array with a `for (i in array)` loop is _essentially arbitrary_. You could sort the output within awk but get ready for some surprise and a lot of verbosity. You are better off using the sort utility that is made for that and does it good and faster than GNU awk's own sort command. http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_130.html

Comment: @Phil, you are right. Associative arrays are a nightmare to traverse in awk. Unpredictable output. But they are so handy for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be my first choice, but you can do this in pure bash (no forks):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u
unset HEADING LINE COUNT
COUNT=0
while read LINE; do
  if [[ "$LINE" =~ '^\* ' ]]; then
    #print previous, if it exists
    declare -p HEADING > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$HEADING [${COUNT}]"

    HEADING=$LINE
    COUNT=0
  elif [[ "$LINE" =~ '^\*\* ' ]]; then
    let COUNT++
  else
    echo "Unexpected input" 1>&2
  fi
done
echo "$HEADING [${COUNT}]"
```

Things to point out:

- `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` is a bash extension allowing regex matches
- `declare -p` is used to test for variable existance
- The script will do funny things if the input isn't as described, e.g. empty lines, lines without the * or ** prefix